# How do you represent fraction in F# without the loss of precision?

Tags: f#, fractions, rational-numbers

What is best way to represent fractions in F#? Haskell and Racket have convinient way to represent ratios. Is there a data type in F# to represent ratios?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [F# Powerpack](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/) which has a `BigRational` (arbitrary precision rational numbers) type:

```
let r = (1N/2N) * (1N/3N) // 1/6
```

Comment: Hi Gabe, is this something that's still viable, or do you know if its been replaced by new F# features?

Comment: @JimDel: As far as I know, Powerpack is still the way to go.

Comment: According to the [F# PowerPack archive on GitHub README](https://github.com/fsprojects/zzarchive-powerpack), BigRational is present in [F# support in Math.Net Numerics](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The `BigRational` type has [F# support in Math.Net Numerics](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/) according to the updated [F# PowerPack archive on GitHub README](https://github.com/fsprojects/zzarchive-powerpack).